# Pourquoi écrit-on "Monsieur de..." ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Que signifie écrire *Monsieur **de/du***..., comme dans les exemples ci-dessous ?

- "Hé ! bonjour, Monsieur **du** Corbeau" (La Fontaine, Fable II, Livre I).
- "Monsieur **de** l'Ours" (Rabelais, II, IV).
- "Le pauvre Monsieur **du** Pape" (Rabelais, I, XXXIII).

Comment: Il me semble que

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À mon avis il s'agit de la [particule nobiliaire](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particule_(onomastique)#La_particule_en_France). Le renard veut flatter le corbeau pour mieux le duper, non seulement il lui donne un titre : *Monsieur*, mais en plus il l'anoblit en lui donnant du « de » (Le Corbeau devenant son nom de famille).

Je n'ai plus Gargantua en tête, mais je pense qu'on peut tenir le même raisonnement pour justifier l'emploi de la particule nobiliaire pour se moquer de quelqu'un qui n'est pas noble, soit pour le flatter, soit pour s'en moquer.